Bits per Pixel calculation
Please can anyone let me know how I can calculate the Bitrate for a Grey scale and color image.
Iam actually calculating it as (WidthheightColor depth*fps)
So please clarify this is same for both Grey scale and color image

You need to specify the encoding method since you have tagged JPEG and I suspect that you actually mean MPEG (or other video encoding format) since you refer to fps in the question. Bitrate in compressed video formats tends to be something that you specify to the compression engine and it does its best to oblige. Raw data is much  bigger. For colour you also need to specify the chroma subsampling to make a decent stab at guessing at the total bit rate. Default chroma subsampling of 4:2:2 means AOBE colour images and video are roughly twice the bitrate of mono.
